# Adding new virtual disks to a Windows host in ESX “live”

Tags: windows, virtualization, storage, vmware-esx

Building on my previous [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/129900/adding-new-virtual-disks-to-a-rhel-host-in-esx-live) about RHEL, how do you add get the guest OS to recognize that you've added new drives to it without a reboot?

I have Windows 2003, XP, and 2008 guests running on ESX 4. I've added new virtual disks to the VM, but have not figured-out how to get the guest to recognize them without a reboot.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to go to the disk management snap-in (diskmgmt.msc) and go to Action -> Rescan Disks.

That will detect any new disks and pop up the windows wizard to initialize them.